# cant chage size of icons inside bar-footer

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a bar-footer:

```
<div class="crop modal">
    <div class="crop-center-container">
        <div class="crop-img" ng-style="{width: width + 'px', height: height + 'px'}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="crop-center-container">
        <div class="crop-select" ng-style="{width: width + 'px', height: height + 'px'}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar bar-footer bar-dark">
        <div class="button-bar">
            <button class="button button-clear crop-button icon ion-ios-close" ng-click="cancel()"></button>
            <button class="button button-clear crop-button icon ion-ios-undo"></button>
            <button class="button button-clear crop-button icon ion-arrow-left-a"></button>
            <button class="button button-clear crop-button icon ion-ios-redo"></button>
            <button class="button button-clear crop-button icon ion-ios-checkmark" ng-click="crop()"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i use icons on that. Now i read in ionic documentation that i can change the size of the icon using the `font-size` so i did:

```
.crop {
    background-color: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.crop-center-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.crop-img {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.crop-select {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.crop-button {
    font-size: 100px !important;
}

.bar.bar-footer {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

I set the font-size to be 50px but nothing changes. I cant change the size of the icons. How can i change them?

Comment: we can't see your icons, add more css

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rftgz8k5/, there might be something else you're missing.

Comment: i posted the complete html and css.

Answer (score 1):

that's because you dont have text between, so you cant set the font-size.

```html
<button class="">TEXT HERE!</button>
```

TEXT HERE!

Comment: in ionic buttons can be used as icon, without text between. And giving font-size styling can change size of icon.